# Save single object to file system

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to know how to save single object(for example user's token) to file system. Is shared preferences best practices? Or it be better to use table with single row or something else?

Comment: shared preferences is recommanded.

Comment: [How to securely store access token and secret in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161266/how-to-securely-store-access-token-and-secret-in-android)

Comment: if you like any answer you can surely upvote it.. but please don't downvote an answer unless it's totally wrong. Thank you :) Cheers!

Comment: I didn't downvote any answer. They are all good and more or less the same. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

If your user token is session based (change at every application launch) then it would be better to save in **application cache**.

If your user token not change as per application life-cycle, then **shared preference** is best option.

Answer (score -1):

Shared prefrences will be the best choice, https://github.com/Pixplicity/EasyPrefs here is a library to make it easier for you aswell